# How do I asynchronously listen to a value in Firestore using an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have an asynchronous function in Flutter which communicates with Firestore. 
There's a server-function that runs, and my indication of the completion of the task a flag that I listen to using StreamSubscription.
The StreamSubscription listening code is wrapped with a Future async function, yet I can't understand how do I return a Future from the function handler of StreamSubscription.

```
static Future<bool> listenToProcess(
  String doc, Function func) {

  StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> stream =  Firestore.instance.collection('requests').document(doc)
      .snapshots().listen((data){
    if (data.data["done"])
      func(true);
    print ("change " + data.data["done"].toString());
  });
```

}

The function should wait for the stream to get a done=true future answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use [`Completer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-async/Completer-class.html) in these situations:

```dart
static Future<bool> listenToProcess(String doc, Function func) {
  final completer = Completer<bool>();
  final stream = Firestore.instance
      .collection('requests').document(doc).snapshots().listen((data) {
        ...
        completer.complete(data.data["done"]);
      });

  return completer.future;
}
```

However, I see that you may have mixed up some concepts here.

1. The name of your function indicates that it is dealing with a `Stream`, however you are returning a `Future`. You should not be using both `Stream` and `Future` concepts in the same function. It is somewhat confusing.
2. You are passing the callback `func`, but those are not meant to be used when you are already returning a `Future`, since you can call `func` when the `Future` resolves.

I would rewrite this function like this:

```dart
static Future<bool> checkIfRequestIsDone(String doc) async {
  // Retrieve only the first snapshot. There's no need to listen to it.
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('requests').document(doc).snapshots().first;

  return snapshot["done"];
}
```

And the caller:

```dart
bool isRequestDone = await checkIfRequestIsDone(doc);

// Call the server-function as soon as you know if the request is done.
// No need for callback.
serverFunction(isRequestDone);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer, the completer worked like a charm. But the isRequestDone approach is not so good since I need to wait until the answer is true. In case of false the code will continue to serverFunction(), no?

Comment: Then check whether `isRequestDone` is true before calling `serverFunction()`: `if (isRequestDone) serverFunction(true);`. I really think you should consider this, since, as I explained, your original implementation in mixing up a lot of concepts.

Comment: Yeah so what I did it to omit the func() code. I don't see how I can simply use if (isRequestDone) since I would have to keep on checking it somehow.. and I surely won't loop through and check, even not with a Timer.. I think the stream approach is ok as long as I cancel it after it changes to true.

Comment: ```Completer``` is amazing! Thanks so much for sharing!