# Flutter Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Local 'name' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-future

I have a flutter app which tries to compare two sets of app version numbers, the first version number is stored locally using hive and the second version number is from firestore. I can fetch the data from firestore but I cannot get to compare both since it takes a while to fetch data from firestore.

This is the code to fetch data from firestore

```
  late final Box detailsBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    detailsBox = Hive.box('appDetails');
    updateApplication();
  }

  CollectionReference groceries =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('updates');

  late String? name;
  late String? version;
  late String? downloadUrl;

  getData()  {
    groceries.orderBy('name').snapshots().listen((gets) {
      try {
        for (var gettt in gets.docs) {
          name = gettt['name'] ?? 'null';
          version = gettt['version'] ?? 'null';
          downloadUrl = gettt['download url'] ?? 'null';

          debugPrint('name: $name');
          debugPrint('version: $version');
          debugPrint('downloadUrl: $downloadUrl');

          _addInfo(name!, version!, downloadUrl!);        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the code to compare the version numbers

```
  int getExtendedVersionNumber(String version) {
    List versionCells = version.split('.');
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(versionCells);
    }
    versionCells = versionCells.map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
    return versionCells[0] * 10000 + versionCells[1] * 100 + versionCells[2];
  }

  Future compareData() async {
    await getData();

    String localName = detailsBox.get('name');
    String localVersion = detailsBox.get('version');
    String downloadLink = detailsBox.get('downloadLink');

    debugPrint(
        'Info retrieved from detailsBox below:\n $localName\n ($localVersion) \n $downloadLink');

    debugPrint(
        'Info retrieved from firebase below:\n $name\n ($version) \n $downloadUrl');

    int version1Number = getExtendedVersionNumber(localVersion); // return 102003
    int version2Number = getExtendedVersionNumber(version!); // return 102003

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(version1Number == version2Number);
      print(version1Number > version2Number);
      print(version1Number < version2Number);
    }
    if (version2Number > version1Number) {
      debugPrint('true');
      debugPrint(downloadUrl);
    }   
  }
```

When it gets to this point     `debugPrint( 'Info retrieved from firebase below:\n $name\n ($version) \n $downloadUrl');` I get the late initialization error  `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized.`

How can I modify the code such that when it runs I can account for the time it takes to get data then finally compare the versions

Comment: Why did you make `name`, `version`, and `downloadUrl` `late` if they're already nullable?  While legal, there isn't much practical sense to doing that. `late` normally is used to *avoid* using a nullable type.

Comment: As for making `compareData` wait for `getData` to complete: `await getData()` won't wait since `getData` does not return a `Future`. [You could make `getData` use a `Completer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450471/) to get a `Future` that completes after the first iteration, or you could make `getData` use `await for` instead of `listen` to wait for all elements (assuming that it is a finite set).

Comment: @jamesdlin I found a way around it. I called ```compareData()```  inside the ```try catch``` in ```getData()```. It solved my issue for now

Comment: Nice to hear your issue got resolved. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
late String? name;
```

to

```
String? name;
```